# How do I get the back button to go to a certain Fragment in horizontal scrolling? Exits app right now

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentpageradapter

the title pretty much explains it.

I have horizontal scrolling set up, the first screen has buttons to the other Fragments as well as the whole horizontal scroll system. What I would like is for the user to be able to press the back button when on one of these fragments and for the app to return to the first screen with all the buttons.

From there I want the back button to be an AlertDialog asking the user if they would like to exit the app. At the moment this is what is happening (On all Fragments when you press the back button the AlertDialog I created pops up).

I've looked into Fragment transactions and "addToBackStack()" but I don't know how to implement it. I've looked at the dev guide and certain questions on this site but getting one or two lines of code doesn't help in implementing it.

I have a FragmentActivity with a FragmentPagerAdapter set up and each Fragment has its own Java file. I have 5 Fragments that are all called in the FragmentActivity and FragmentPagerAdapter.

I don't think I need to show you guys any of my code for the moment since it's all set up in the normal manner. Please let me know if you do though.

The bit of code I found on other questions and one in particular was the following:

```
FragmentTransaction tx = fragmentManager.beginTransation();
tx.replace( R.id.fragment, new MyFragment() ).addToBackStack( "tag" ).commit();
```

It's a bit hard to go on just that though.

I would really appreciate your help.

EDIT: my code removed - wasn't needed.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, mainly because you don't properly explain how your layout works. Also, *I have horizontal scrolling set up* , I guess you're referring to a `ViewPager` with fragments(?!).

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'm using a ViewPager with Fragments in a FragmentActivity. I think I'll post my code, give me a sec

Comment: @Luksprog: I've added my code, hopefully it's formatted well enough to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `ViewPager` from your question which I answered earlier and you want to come back to the first fragment of the `ViewPager` when the user presses the `BACK` button then override the `onBackPressed` method like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("outDialog") != null
            && ((DialogFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag("outDialog")).isVisible()) {
        // we have the out dialog visible and the user clicked back so let
        // the
        // normal events happen
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }
    int currentPosition = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
    if (currentPosition != 0) {
        // if the page the ViewPager shows isn't the first one then move it
        // to the first one
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    } else {
        // we are at the first position already and the user wants out, so
        // annoy him with a dialog that asks him once again if he wants out.
        DialogFragment askHim = new DialogFragment();
        askHim.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "outDialog");
        // in the dialog listener, if the user presses ok, finish the activity
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I'm currently getting a force close with this code, the stack trace cites line 105 which is this line: int currentPosition = mViewPager.getCurrentItem(); I'll keep playing around with it and see what I come up with.

Comment: @RED_ That is something related to your code. As you didn't mention what is the exception, make sure that `mViewPager` points to your `ViewPager` and it isn't `null`.

Comment: Hmm, The error happens when I press the back button, a NullPointerException. When I comment out that bit of code around line 105 I don't get a FC but then obviously the back button becomes useless. That bit of code looks perfectly logical so I'll keep looking. I added a variable at the top of my code to point to the ViewPager. "ViewPager mViewPager;" This refers to my ViewPager in the code I posted in my question so I doubt it would be null.

Comment: @RED_ You should have a field in your activity: `private ViewPager mViewpager;` which you'll initialize in the `onCreate` method of the activity : `mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.mysixpanelpager);`. Is this what you currently have? If yes, that would be very awkward.

Comment: just before the onCreate I have "ViewPager mViewPager;" Without private. I just tried it with private however and it comes to the same conclusion, the same FC. That's the only extra bit I added other than actual onBackPressed()

Comment: @RED_ Yes, but in your code, in the `onCreate` method you have `ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.mysixpanelpager);` . Notice how you declare a local variable *mViewPager* of type `ViewPager`. Do it like this `mViewPager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.mysixpanelpager);` . If this doesn't work then double check your code, you nullify the `mViewPager` variable somewhere.

Comment: Was just about to edit my last comment, essentially just did what you said and part of it is working now. Pressing the back button gets me to the first Fragment. I see where I went wrong. Pressing the back button on the first fragment doesn't do anything however. I don't know what "outDialog" is referring to since I haven't tagged any of my Fragments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21871/discussion-between-luksprog-and-red)

Answer (score 0):

did you try to override `Activity.onBackPressed()` ? 
I used `addToBackStack()` and it works well, but I have no idea whether it works with `PagerAdapter`.
I think you can override `Activity.onBackPressed()` and in that method, you can check whether current page is front page or not and do whatever job you want to do.

Here are pseudo code that I think.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
  if( pager.getCurrentPage() == 0 ) { //I'm not sure this method exists or not. just example. :-)
      //exit code here
  } else {
      // show first page
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I've seem something similar where Fragments where not used. Thanks for the pseudo code I'll look into it.