# Handle Back Button When I Press Webpage(Not using Webview for opening Webpage)

Tags: android, android-webview

Could any one Help me to solve this issue?

**For Opening WebPage I am using like this**

```
String url = "https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=ctrl&ei=AdcNU6WYDajM8gfB8YHIAQ&gws_rd=cr"
                    intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
```

I wanna display dialog when i press back button from that view

My question is,"How can i write code for back button press"?(Notes : **I am not using Webview**)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

You have to override `OnBackPressed()` Function.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Exit");
    builder.setMessage("Are You Sure?");

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // do your stuff here
            }
        });

    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay .Could u tell me how to do same thing in Fragment?

Comment: Well for that you can check here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071233/how-do-i-get-the-back-button-to-go-to-a-certain-fragment-in-horizontal-scrolling and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052996/going-back-in-fragments-by-pressing-the-back-button